# Ways to speed up this list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a problem where I need to compare large lists of file paths to be processed with a list of files that have already been processed.
I don't want to just change the string within remaining to match the strings in original list because that will break the portability (also the strings are actually a lot more complicated than in the example).
Is there a more efficient way of generating the final jobs variable?

```
original_list = [f'{x}.wav' for x in range(100000)]
output_list = [f'{x}.npy' for x in range(100000)]
already_done = [f'{x}.npy' for x in range(10000)]
jobs = list(zip(original_list, output_list))
remaining = list(set(output_list).difference(already_done))
jobs = [(x,y) for x,y in jobs if y in remaining]
```

Comment: Do you need to check if the file in `already_done` exists? Is this list already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Checking for membership in a list is expensive, so let `remaining` be a `set` instead of converting it to a list. Also, you don't need to convert `jobs` to a list. Let it be an iterator that you get from `zip()` and evaluate its elements only once when you need them in the list comprehension.

```
original_list = [f'{x}.wav' for x in range(100000)]
output_list = [f'{x}.npy' for x in range(100000)]
already_done = [f'{x}.npy' for x in range(10000)]
jobs = zip(original_list, output_list)
remaining = set(output_list).difference(already_done)
jobs = [(x,y) for x,y in jobs if y in remaining]
```

Comment: `jobs` could also stay as a `zip`, sice you're iterating it once (If you need it later, then a list is OK).

Comment: @aaossa good point, `jobs = zip()` is overwritten by the list comprehension so you won't end up needing that `zip()` later.